# Catching stderr custom output in try catch python

Tags: python, io

I have a function that will write to stderr when an error occurs:

```
class Scanner:
    ...

    def next(self):
       if ...
            ...
            if not open_comment_count == closed_comment_count:
                        ...
                        sys.stderr.write("error: unclosed comment at position ({0}, {1})".format(start_position, end_position))
                        ...
                        break
            ...

       else:
            sys.stderr.write("error: illegal character \'{0}\' found " \
                          "at position @({1}, {2})".format(self.input_text[self.curr_position],
                                                           self.curr_position, self.curr_position))
                    error_flag = 1
                    break
      if error_flag == 0:
            token = Token(kind=4, eof_value="eof", start_position=self.curr_position, end_position=self.curr_position)
            return token
```

the function is very long so I included the parts where I write to `stderr`. What I would like to do is when those errors occur, I want to print those errors and terminate the program. So in my main, I would like to have:

```
def main():
    s = Scanner(input_string)
    try:
        while(True):
            s.next()
    except:
        # print error message and stop
```

What i am stuck on is what should the exception be. I want to somehow catch that something was written to stderr and I want that caught and printed out in main and then the program to stop. Basically running until an exception occurs. I know this can be done by writing my own exception, but is it possible to just check if something was written to stderr and then print it out?

Comment: If you want this to behave like an exception, just make it an exception.  You could also have an error function that first writes to stderr and then throws an exception.

Comment: That said, you could move the logic to a subprocess, and then kill the subprocess when something is written to stderr.  Or you could monkey-patch `sys.stderr` with an object that throws an exception when `write()` is called.  But all those solutions are rather weird compared to the straight-forward solution of simply throwing an exception.

Comment: Why not use `except Exception as e` to catch all Exception and print it out. To catch the stderr, you can use a `stderrio=StringIO()` and give it to `sys.stderr=stderrio` and then check its content.

Comment: @platinhom that is what i am trying to do, could you possibly put this as an answer? i tried writing except Exception as e but i didn't know if there was a `e.print_stack_trace()` that would print my custom error string

Comment: @ platinhom This worked. I caught the exception with `catch Exception as e` and printed `e.strerror` which printed my custom error string and exited the program. Thanks

Comment: It's good. Indeed I don't exactly know your need so I don't make an answer ╮(╯▽╰)╭

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do mixes up concerns: reporting an error becomes a signal that there has *been* an error. You could do that by creating a wrapper for `stderr` that sets some kind of flag:

```
import sys

class MyStdErr(object):

    stderr = sys.stderr
    waserr = False

    def write(self, text):
        self.waserr = True
        self.stderr.write(text)

sys.stderr = MyStdErr()
```

Now `sys.stderr.waserr` is `True` if `stderr` was written to at any point.

I think raising an exception containing the error message, catching it, and printing the error (as shown by Nathan) is considerably better, however.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing to stderr is there a reason you cant just raise errors with what you're writing to stderr as the message? Then you can just catch whatever error you decide to raise. Something like

```
class Scanner:
...

def next(self):
   if ...
        ...
        if not open_comment_count == closed_comment_count:
                    ...
                    raise InputError("error: unclosed comment at position ({0}, {1})".format(start_position, end_position))
                    ...
                    break
        ...

   else:
        raise InputError("error: illegal character \'{0}\' found " \
                      "at position @({1}, {2})".format(self.input_text[self.curr_position],
                                                       self.curr_position, self.curr_position))
                error_flag = 1
                break
  if error_flag == 0:
        token = Token(kind=4, eof_value="eof", start_position=self.curr_position, end_position=self.curr_position)
        return token
```

and then

```
def main():
s = Scanner(input_string)
try:
    while(True):
        s.next()
except InputError as e:
    print e
```

EDIT
to address your comment, yes. And if you want do do it with a custom error name you can do

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

and then `raise MyException('message')`

Comment: So I can override Python's inherent errors which write to stderr and pass my own error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cause an exception when you write to stderr, then close stderr. Now when some function writes to stderr, I guess it will get an IOError. Getting the error message will be harder.

You could catch all exceptions and print out the exception, but this still won't capture the message to stderr.